# Why can't I log an error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

I have an ASP.NET 2010 app. Basically, anywhere I have reason to suspect an error I employ the following technique in order to attempt to log it.

```
Try

'Code causing error here

Catch ex As Exception When LogException(ex)
Catch ex As Exception 'Here is where I would put a more specific error

End Try
```

The LogException function ALWAYS returns false. Therefore, every exception should be caught and logged and then control falls back to the next exception in the block. What really happens is the LogException function is called, but before it can do anything, control goes right back to the next exception in the block above. Why?

Edit...Here is the function that is getting called but returning fter the 1st line...

```
Public Function LogException(ByVal ex As Exception) As Boolean
        Dim oExceptionMgt As New ExceptionMgt 'This line runs
        oExceptionMgt.LogException(ex) 'This line should go to db to log error. 
Return False
    End Function
```

Comment: If it is always false would it not skip that condition?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not a VB programmer. What code does the `LogException` function contain? Is it possible that that function is itself throwing an exception?

Comment: The LogException function returns false last.; ie supposedly AFTER it logs the error to the db. But, instead of going to the db, it skips the code and just returns.

Comment: post the code, we are not mindreaders.

Comment: Once again, you have yet to show us the code that actually interacts with the database.

Comment: Aren't you trying to do the following? 
Catch ex as Exception When Not LogException(ex)

Answer (score 0):

While I am not a VB programmer if I see a condition such as:

```
do something when somecondition
```

That logically says only do `something` when `somecondition` is true.  Therefore in your example the code is executing correctly because your `LogException(Exception ex)` method is always false.  Which in turn means don't do the `something` in this instance and continue executing.

Comment: Please understand the method does reutnr false, liek you say, but AFTER it should go to the db and log the error. Please see above for this function which I'll add now.

Comment: please show the code that actually interacts with the database, you have yet to do so.